# Propositional calculus proof must involve instance of $(\neg \neg p \Rightarrow p )$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Hi this is a question about propositional calculus. The axioms I am working with are:

1. $(p \Rightarrow (q\Rightarrow p))$
2. $ ((p \Rightarrow (q \Rightarrow r)) \Rightarrow ((p \Rightarrow q ) \Rightarrow (p \Rightarrow r)))$
3. $(\neg \neg p \Rightarrow p )$

Now, consider $t$ a propositional formula not involving the constant $\bot$, and let $t′ = t[\bot/p]$ be the formula obtained from $t$ by substituting $\bot$ for all occurrences of the propositional variable $p$ in $t.$

If $t′$ is a tautology but $t$ is not, I wish to show that any proof of $t′$ must involve an instance of the third axiom.

Any help with this would be really appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: How about $ \lnot \lnot \bot \to \bot $ also do you really mean $ \lnot \lnot p \to p $  or $\(( p \to \bot) \to \bot ) \to p $  to be a bit pedantic you have given no axioms for  $\bot $ at all and only an elimination axiom for $\lnot $ so they are really just symbols. (the definitions you use and the inference rules should be mentioned, in axiomatic logic nothing is presumed )

Comment: @Willemien - the above is *Church's axioms system* for propositional logic [see Wiki or Alonzo Church, *Introduction to Mathematical Logic* (1956), page 72]: of course, rules of inference are needed; Church uses *modus *ponens* and *substitution*. Removing the third axiom, we obtain *Łukasiewicz's axiom system* for the positive implicational calculus is the implicational fragment of intuitionistic logic.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA was thinking about that, he just wants an axiomatic proof of (peirce law)[ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peirce_law ] I stumbled on it yesterday but forgot where, so now cant reproduce it, but still there is a problem with his axioms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a proof of $t'$ that use only axioms 1 and 2. If you take the entire proof and replace every $\bot$ with $p$, you get something that is still a valid proof, because none of the axioms you're working with treat $\bot$ any different from an arbitrary propositional variable. The conclusion of the rewritten proof is $t'[p/\bot]$, but given your assumptions, that is just $t$.

However, the existence of a proof of $t$ contradicts the assumption that $t$ is not a tautology.

Comment: you have considered a proof of $t'$ where $t'$ contains $p$; but the formula with $p$ is $t$, and the problem do not says that we have a proof of $t$ (and we don't, being $t$ not a tautology). We can tahke as $t$ the formula $\lnot p \lor q$ that is not *taut*, and we have that $t'$ will be $\lnot \bot \lor q$, i.e. a *taut* ... if I do not made mistakes ...

Comment: @Mauro: No, $t'$ does not contain $p$ -- by the assumptions all $p$s there have been replaced by $\bot$.

Comment: @Mauro: Your example is probably not a valid one because I strongly suspect the OPs system considers $\neg p$ an abbreviation of $p\to\bot$, so your $t=(p\to\bot)\lor q$ is not $\bot$-free like the question specified. And if $\neg p$ is _not_ such an abbreviation, then it's certainly true that your $t'$ cannot be proved without axiom 3 (because it cannot be proved in the system at all, since none of the axioms mention $\bot$ or for that matter $\lor$).

Comment: You are right, thanks ! You can "invert" the substitution because the problem says : "consider $t$ a propositional formula **not** involving the constant $\bot$ [emphasis added]".

Comment: I'm still confused - what is the "correct" interpretation of the "axiom system" of the OP's question ? We need some rules of inference: I assume *modus ponens*, but what about *substitution* ? So, may we have formulas $t$ [without $\bot$] with $\lnot$ inside ? If I stay with the interpretation that $\bot$ is not primitive in the system, I may certainly prove $\vdash p \rightarrow p$ from the two first axioms. And what about a formula like : $p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow q)$ that is *not* taut, but with $\bot$ in place of $p$ will become *taut* ?

Comment: We may consider also as $t$ the following: $p \rightarrow (p \rightarrow q)$; it is pure implicational and it is *not* taut, so it is not provable from axioms 1 & 2 only. Then $t'$ will be : $\bot \rightarrow (\bot \rightarrow q)$ and it is a tautology. So, being a substitution instance of $t$, and being $t'$ a taut, if we allow subst, in order to prevent $t$ being provable, we must exclude $\bot$ from the primitive system. Now, my doubt is : why must be evident that in order to prove $t'$ we need axiom 3 ? We must appeal to *completeness*...

Comment: @Mauro: It is evident that axioms 1 and 2 alone cannot prove $\bot\to(\bot\to q)$, because if there were such a proof, replacing every $\bot$ in it with $p$ would produce a proof if $p\to(p\to q)$, and such a proof cannot exist. What do you need completeness for? Note that it is not claimed that it _can_ be proved using axiom 3, only that IF it has a proof, that proof will include axiom 3.

Comment: When you say that "such a proof cannot exist" you are asserting it because the statement of the problem says that $t$ is not a taut: and this is *soundness*. And being $t'$ a tautology, I appeal to *completenss* and I conclude that it MUST have a proof. Or I'm making a mistake ...

Comment: @Mauro: The point is that nobody's asking you to conclude that it must have proof, so the appeal to completeness is superfluous.

Comment: Right ! Thanks ...